# Openlayers : Zoom In and Map Layers Blocked wih WHITE space

Tags: openlayers-2

I've a problem where something is blocking my map layer when I zoomed the map
[click to view](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8zbg3KhJCOgZDVjUzlmcHFudk0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function load() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(101.076797485352, 3.60602392425537,101.077194213867, 3.60696087346802)

        });
    // setup tiled layer
    floorplan7 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "assetmapper:floor_plan_t7 - Tiled", "http://192.168.56.101:8080/geoserver/assetmapper/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'assetmapper:floor_plan_t7',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format: 'image/png',

                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                //    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
                } 
        );


map.addLayers([floorplan7]);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({}));
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

}
```

What should I do to clear the 'WHITE' area?